# Getting variables in the URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need that when I write http://www.mysite.com/username
the username is sent as a parameter to index.php

example: http://www.mysite.com/index.php?user=username

how can I do with htaccess? you have other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write rule in your htaccess like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?uniqname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?uniqname=$1 [QSA]
```

To add folders use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^avatars/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?uniqname=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^avatars/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?uniqname=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Why not `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ index.php?uniqname=$1 [QSA]` instead?

Comment: if there is any thing wrong in my answer then please guide me

Comment: perfect, just that if I have folders?

example if I http://mysite.com/avatars
But I also have a folder called "avatars" how can I do?

Comment: i think you want to make like this http://www.mysite.com/avatars/username Am I right?

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then please vote this answer so it will be useful to others too.

Comment: @Hardik The reason I added `/?` is because `?` in regex means `repeated 0 or 1 time`, then therefore you wouldn't need your second line (as it'd already be included by saying "either end with a slash or don't").

Comment: @Hardik I need some names for this rule is not applied because on the server, there are folder might be called as a user name?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to read the *username* variable in the PHP of the requested page?

In PHP you would do this, in it's most basic form

```
    <?php echo $_GET['username']; ?> // That will print the variable value on the page
```

Important. If you are using this to get or edit data in a database you need to clean or [sanitize that variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) first to prevent against SQL Injection Attacks. A rough example of this is as such

```
    <?php 
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username'];
    echo $username;
    ?>
```

You may also want to have more of a read of [PHP GET and POST variables.](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following RewriteRules:

```
//Only one parameter that defines username
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1

//If you need second parameter or a number only parameter
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?username=$1&paramnumber=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?username=$1&paramstring=$2
```